# Cannot access memory at address in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I've got a linked list of nodes that contain a string of characters. The program reads characters from *stdin* until it reaches a new line and once it has it puts this string of characters into the a new node of the list.

I've done some debugging of the different steps involved in the program and can see the list of nodes being created correctly.

[image]

However, the printf statement doesn't seem to do anything if I'm stepping through the code. If I don't step through and just run the code through I get:

Cannot access memory at address 0x2e666564

Cannot access memory at address 0x2e666564

Cannot access memory at address 0x2e666564

My source code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char *string;
    struct Node *next;
} List;

List *addNode(List *currentList, char *character)
{
    List *tempList = calloc(1, sizeof(List));
    tempList->string = strdup(character);
    tempList->next = currentList;

    return tempList;
}

void printList(List *currentList)
{
    while (currentList != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", currentList->string);
        currentList = currentList->next;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    char currentCharacter;
    char *currentString;
    List *mainList = NULL;

    do 
    {
        currentCharacter = getchar();
        if (currentCharacter == '\n')
        {
            mainList = addNode(mainList, currentString);
            currentString[0] = '\0';
        } else {
            strcat(currentString, &currentCharacter);
        }
    } while (currentCharacter != '.');

    mainList = addNode(mainList, currentString);


    printList(mainList);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling strcat on an invalid pointer.

Something like this would work:

```
char currentString[128];
currentString[0] = '\0';
```

currentCharacter isn't null-terminated and so strcat won't work. Use strncat instead.

Comment: he'll need to put the character some place other than currentString[0] at some point.

Answer (score 4):

Several problems here.

The main problem is that you have not allocated space for your currentString. strcat requires that there be space in the destination array (currentString).

Also problematic: when the user enters '\n', you haven't null terminated the string you are appending, so strdup will not quite work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `main` function never initializes `currentString` to point to allocated memory, so your call to `strcat` just starts adding characters to whatever `'\0'`-terminated string `currentString` happens to be pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strcat`.  You do need to assign `currentString` at some point.  Replace:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 128
/*
   shouldn't need more than 128 characters for a line of console
   but you can expand it later if you want
*/
int main() {
    List *mainList = NULL;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFER_SIZE);
    int currentIndex = 0;
    char currentCharacter;

    do {
        currentCharacter = getChar();
        if (currentCharacter == '\n' || currentIndex == (BUFFER_SIZE-1))
            buffer[currentIndex] = 0;                     //the null byte needs to be added before strdup is called
            mainList = addNode(mainList, buffer);
            currentIndex = 0;
        } else {
            buffer[currentIndex++] = currentCharacter;
        }
    } while (currentCharacter != '.');

    mainList = addNode(mainList, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```